# How to have brackets completion in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want my terminal to automatically close my brackets, quotation marks, etc.

For example, I want to type `(` and I want it to complete to

```
(|)
```

where | represents the mouse cursor.

Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Reimplement GNU Readline, that's the thing that gives you history and the ability to move your cursor.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` reads `~/.inputrc` file, which allows binding certain keys to macros. In our case, we need macro that automatically types in "()" and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (which is move back one word ) shortcut.

Open the file with gedit or any other text editor and type in the following

```
 "\C-]":"()\C-b"
```

That will bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to do what you want. Now open terminal or call a new instance of the shell and test it out.

You can try binding it to any other keyboard short-cut, but there is only so much you can do.